# Would the Earth appear to be spinning off center when viewed from geostationary orbit?

Tags: science-based, earth, space-constructs, geostationary-orbit, appearance

In *2001:A Space Odyssey*, from Space Station V the Earth appears to be spinning around a center that is near the edge of the planet.
[Phone call from space station scene](https://youtu.be/vWwo6JpMceg?t=19)

If the same station (300 meters in diameter) was in a geostationary orbit (35,786 km from the Earth), would the apparent center of spin of the Earth appear to be at the center of the planet, or slightly off center of the planet's center to the human eye?  Using Earth's diameter as 12,750 km.

Comment: Looking at that clip, the speed of the rotation makes me think that it's more the station's rotation than the planet's rotation

Comment: The answer is in the question.  Geo-stationary: the earth will appear stationary from the perspective of the station.

Comment: If an astronaut was floating freely at a geostationary orbit and spun around with the axis of their rotation pointing to the Earth, wouldn't the Earth appear to spin in the opposite direction of their rotation?

Comment: @Andon: Certainly seems that way. Not only that but given that we now know the rotation speed of the station and the apparent 1g that the astronaut is sitting at we can calculate a minimum diameter for the station.

Comment: @JoeBloggs Yes, the rotation of the station is making the Earth appear to spin (not rotate) about a point near the edge.  Would the spin appear to be about a point corresponding to the center of the Earth from geostationary orbit, or off-center?

Comment: Yes the rest of the universe will appear as the earth would be spinning around you and the earth presenting the same face to you exactly as the moon does.

Comment: It depends entirely on how the observer's axis of rotation is oriented relative to the Earth. It need no be pointing at the Earth at all.

Answer (score 4):

From geostationary orbit, by definition, the Earth will always present the same face.  The terminators (sunrise and sunset lines) will creep across the surface, but the portion of the Earth that is visible (nearly 50% of the surface, cloud cover and lighting permitting) will not change (assuming the slight oversimplification of an orbital position that doesn't need frequent adjustment due to perturbation).

Any rotation you might see would be, as it likely was in that *2001* clip, due to the movement of the spacecraft or station you're viewing the Earth from.  **The apparent center of rotation will always be along the station's axis**; if that points through the Earth at all, it will do it twice each orbit, and the Earth will appear to rotate around that axis (as the sun and moon appear to turn around the Earth's axis from the surface) and also move fore and aft (taking the axes to be forward and rearward) over multiple rotations (since the station's rotation is much less than an hour).

Answer (score 1):

## The rotation you're describing is impossible.

A planet rotates around its center of mass. The only way for this to occur is if its center of mass were to lie outside of the body. This can't happen, unless somehow the edge of the planet was significantly denser (and thus more massive) than the rest of the planet. But if the mass of the planet is high enough to make the planet spherical, denser materials always sink towards the center and lighter materials towards the surface.

Ignoring if this was possible and just accepting it as an occurrence, then in a geostationary orbit:

## The planet would appear to be stationary to the space station. No rotation at all would be observable.

Comment: I was asking about the Earth appearing to rotate, as in the video clip from the movie, not actually rotating.  Would saying the Earth is spinning around a point that is near its edge of the planet be more acceptable?

Comment: "the Earth is spinning around a point that is near its edge of the planet" is the way I interpreted the question from the very beginning.

Comment: Is the video clip showing the Earth spinning around not accurate?

Comment: @Bob516 As others have stated, it is more likely that the station _itself_ is rotating, which could cause the phenomenon from the video.

Comment: Yes, it is the rotation of the station that is causing the visual phenomenon.  If the station were to be moved to geostationary orbit, would the phenomenon of the Earth spinning, appear to be about the center of the Earth, or off-center, given the distance from the Earth and the size of the station?

Comment: @Bob516 That would depend on a lot of things. The orbit of the station and the rotation of the station are independent of one another. But if the view of the space station is centered on the Earth, the Earth would visibly appear to be spinning in place about its center.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/99932/discussion-between-bob516-and-overlord).